# refining alignat

Tags: alignat

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
\cos \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&& \sum_{|A|=2k} & \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j \\
\sin \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&& \sum_{|A|=2k+1} & \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j
\end{alignat}
```

It seems that "alignat" aligns everything either on the right or on the left.  However, in the interest of a sort of poetic rhythm that I think may actually aid understanding and reduce distractions, it seems like a good idea for the two giant Sigmas with subscripts `|A|=2k` and `|A|=2k+1` should be aligned with each other, and they're not because of the difference in the subscripts.

So how should that be done?

Also, the subscript `2k+1` is uncomfortably close to the subscript `j\in A` that follows it.  How should that be dealt with?

**Postscript in response to the answer and comments below:** I've just run TeXworks on the document that I quote in its entirety below. I still get this: "Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed."

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[M#1 {$\scriptstyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

trigonometric identities

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried adding '\phantom{{}+1}' to the subscript '|A|=2k', and the Sigmas did get aligned, but then the subscript '|A|=2k' in the first one ends up looking stupidly badly positioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two alignments will do.You can use the  `eqparbox` package, and the `\smashoperator` command from `mathtools`. Two compilations are necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
 \newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[M#1]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\cos \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&& \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{\eqmathbox[i]{|A|=2k}}} \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j \\
\sin \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&&\smashoperator[l]{ \sum_{\eqmathbox[i]{|A|=2k+1}}} \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ran into an error message with this.  I'm wondering if that's because of another package I'm using.  To be continued....

Comment: Did you load `mathtools`, not merely `amsmath`?

Comment: I've got exactly the three lines that you wrote under '\documentclass{article}'. They're the last three lines before my '\begin{document}'.  (But I haven't yet tried it without any other packages.)

Comment: Console output: Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Mike/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Comment: The quoted console output appeared when I ran a version that had no other instances of \usepackage{}.  However, I have another suspicion about where the problem may be: I used some macros.  To be continued.....

Comment: . . . and now I've tried it when my entire LaTeX document is what you see below, and the problem is still there:

    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{eqparbox}
    \newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[M#1 {$\scriptstyle#2$}}

    \begin{document}

    trigonometric identities

    \end{document}

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I'm back  again. Could you post somewhere the exact code you compile and the .log file?

Comment: . . . and _now_ I find the code in your answer works.  (I haven't yet tried it in the original document in which I was using some other packages --- just the file in your answer.  To be continued....

Answer (score 1):

One needs to fine-tune both the *horizontal* alignment of the sum and product symbols **and** the *vertical* placement of the symbols in the limits of summation/multiplication. For the latter, I suggest you insert `\mathstrut` instructions in all subscript positions. For the former, I suggest a combination of `\mathclap` (on all subscript terms) and a selected `\mkern`("math kern") statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap and \DeclarePairedDelimiter macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\cos\sum_{\mathstrut j}\alpha_j
&= \sum_{\mathstrut\mathclap{k=0}}^\infty (-1)^k
   \sum_{\mathstrut\mathclap{\smash{\abs{A}=2k}}} \mkern21mu
   \prod_{\mathstrut\mathclap{j\in A}} \sin\alpha_j
   \prod_{\mathstrut\mathclap{j\notin A}} \cos\alpha_j \\
\sin\sum_{\mathstrut j}\alpha_j
&= \sum_{\mathstrut\mathclap{k=0}}^\infty (-1)^k
   \sum_{\mathstrut\mathclap{\abs{A}=2k+1}} \mkern21mu
   \prod_{\mathstrut\mathclap{j\in A}} \sin\alpha_j
   \prod_{\mathstrut\mathclap{j\notin A}} \cos\alpha_j
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in the interest of providing a simple answer for those who don't have the patience for the extra work required for more sophisticated solutions. The OP didn't like the result of `\phantom{+1}`, but it is possible to simply distribute it either side of the subscript to get a nicer result. Note the use of the `\enspace`, taking advantage of the `\alignat` spacing feature (hence why it is only needed on the first line), to put a little space between `|A| = 2k + 1` and `j \in A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
\cos \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&& \sum_{\phantom{+}|A|=2k\phantom{1}} &\enspace \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j \\
\sin \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&& \sum_{|A|=2k+1} &\  \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like the space between the second two sums, that's a question of taste, then there are two simple solutions for that. The first is to rearrange the use of `&` in the original code, so the problem sum is before the alignment `&` instead of after. This tightens things a little bit.

```
\cos \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
& \sum_{\phantom{+}|A|=2k\phantom{1}} & &\enspace \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j \\
\sin \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
& \sum_{|A|=2k+1} & & \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j
```

[image]

If that's not enough, the second solution is to use a negative `\hskip` in front of the last sum in both rows. But this only works in the original arrangement, that is, after the alignment `&` not the spacing `&`.

```
\cos \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&&\hskip-0.5em \sum_{\phantom{+}|A|=2k\phantom{1}} &\enspace \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j \\
\sin \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&&\hskip-0.5em \sum_{|A|=2k+1} & \prod_{j\in A} \sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j
```

[image]